# Eclipse IDE error - Ready State Poller has encontered a problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-boot-actuator, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting this error with every project with actuator dependency "Ready State Poller has encontered a problem: An internal error occurred during: "Ready state poller".
ATTR_PROCESS_ID"

[Ready State Poller has encontered a problem: An internal error occurred during: "Ready state poller".
ATTR_PROCESS_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM4qr.png)

No stacktrace, project starts normally, just the eclipse IDE error message. How can I prevent this to happen?

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>demo.bootcamp</groupId>
<artifactId>pruebasClientes</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>pruebasClientes</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is a demo project for a bootcamp class, it has only 3 or 4 classes, I think my problem is in the config or in the pom.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with a vanilla STS 4.16.0 installation and a fresh workspace? If so, please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a few steps how to reproduce this. That would be awesome help to investigate this in depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine this issue, Same problem appears.

https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-ide/issues/182

Comment: ...you can examine until "black out", but better: upgrade "spring ide": "This project has reached its EOL and is not maintained anymore. See the announcement on the blog for details: https://spring.io/blog/2022/06/14/goodbye-spring-ide-welcome-spring-tools-4"